# Objective C View Not Moving With Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I am using the following code on a textview in my application. I have made it so when the keyboard triggers that the view will go up on top of the keyboard and when I click outside of the keyboard and the textview, it will close off the keyboard. The problem I am having is when I click the textview there is a delay of the textview moving on top of the keyboard for about 5 seconds then it pops up, also when I click to close the keyboard it vanishes straight away and does not animate like the keyboard does opening. Is there any way I can fix this and animate the view to move on top of the keyboard as it opens and closes instead of jumping?

Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(didShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(didHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];


        _theTextView.delegate = self;
    _theTextView.text = @"Type your message..";
    _theTextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; //optional
    _theTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    _theTextView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [_theTextView resignFirstResponder];
}
- (void)didShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    self.textViewPOS.constant = keyboardSize.height;

    NSLog(@"Opened");
}

- (void)didHide
{
     self.textViewPOS.constant = 0;
    NSLog(@"Closed");
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSLog(@"typing");
    return YES;
}
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@"Type your message.."]) {
        textView.text = @"";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //optional
    }
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textView.text = @"Type your message..";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; //optional
    }
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you try to use UIKeyboardWillShowNotification?

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko That makes it work straight away yeah thanks, but is there any way to animate the view at the speed of the keyboard opening and closing? Because right now it just jumps to the position then the keyboard catches up.

Comment: Past this code under self.textViewPOS.constant = keyboardSize.height;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
           [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
           
        }];

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the delay problem you can use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` as  Eugene Zaychenko suggest. it will solve your issue.

```
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(willShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

For the animation use following code

```
- (void)didHide
{
    self.textViewPOS.constant = 0;
    NSLog(@"Closed");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

        self.textViewPOS.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:nil];

}

- (void)willShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

        self.textViewPOS.constant = keyboardSize.height;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"Opened");
}
```

Let me know if any query.

Answer (score 1):

Does this delay occurs only when you first execute your project?

1. Then in application did finish launching with option (in appdeligate) simply make a textview using code.
2. Then add it our view.Then make textview as first responder.
3. Then resign it as first responder..
4. Then finally remove the textview from our superview.

Your delay issue would be solved by this.